# How do I draw something in a JPanel after I already called the paintComponent method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

I'm new to making GUIs in Java. As I understand, there's a class called Graphics which is in charge of drawing shapes in a JPanel. When my application starts, I call the paintComponent method, which draws the board of the game I'm programming, and the paintComponent method takes a Graphics g as input. However, later on, I want to update the board, so how do I tell the same g that drew the board at the start of the game to draw something else when the user does something like clicking?

I believe this should have a very simple answer.

Comment: You'll want to take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 2):

Every JComponent (Swing component) has a `repaint()` method, just call it to tell the `DrawingManager` to redraw your component.

All your drawing code should be in `paintComponent` method, that means that you don't draw anything anywhere else (you draw only in the flow of invocation of `paintComponent`, you can have drawing code structured in methods of course).

This method needs to have access to the state that indicates what and where should be drawn. It is because the OS could request repainting, and then only the painting methods from `JComponent` are called.

When you invoke `repaint()` on your `JComponent`, then in short time the `paintComponent()` method of the component on which you requested repainting will be called by the drawing thread, and you should draw only in this drawing thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try repaint() or revalidate(), it should work.

Comment: What is the repaint() method? Do I have to override some void repaint() method higher in the hierarchy?

Comment: When you add something you call the repaint() method to tell the program you have added some new element, so at the end of your operations, insert repaint();

Answer (score 0):

> I call the paintComponent method

No, you should never call the paintComponent() method directly. Swing will call the method for you when the component needs to be repainted.

> I want to update the board

Then you need a "setter" method. Think of other Swing components. They have methods like "setForeground(), setBackground(), setText()" etc.

So if you want to change your component then you need to create appropriate setter method to change the properties of your class. Then in the method you save the property and simply invoke `repaint()` and Swing will repaint your component. So now your paintComponent() method needs to check the property you just set to do the appropriate painting.

```
public void setSomeProperty(Obect someProperty)
{
    this.someProperty = someProperty;
    repaint();
}

....

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent();

    //  paint the board

    if (someProperty != null)
        // paint the property
}
```

Comment: This is what I was afraid of having to do. Is it possible to avoid having to put a ton of if statements in the paintComponent method?

Comment: Don't know enough about your game to make any other suggestion. The point is that you understand how painting works and then come up with your own solution. Maybe your game has "game pieces" that are painted on different squares. Then in this case you might keep an ArrayList of game pieces. Then your painting code would iterate through the ArrayList and paint each game piece. So the painted logic is the same whether you have 1 or 100 piece. You just need a method to add/remove a game piece from the list.